# Using js/css compression frameworks at both asp/aspx files

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, system.web.optimization, combres

I have a website which has both asp and aspx pages. Can I use System.Web.Optimization, Combres etc frameworks for both.

Another problem is that these pages doesn't have code-behind as they are generated from the same template at deployment time. Also, I don't have any bin folder at root of website, but at individual virtual directories in IIS. That is, my root of website only has these static asp/aspx files, global.ascx, web.config, css and js files.

So, I can't use something like below because these DLL's doesn't exist at root bin folder:

- `<%=System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/AdminJS.js")%>`
- `<%=Url.CombresLink("AdminJS") %>`

A simple solution like `<script type='text/javascript' src='/cms/bundling/scripts/admin.js?v=123'></script>`
Let me know if more clarity is required.

It shall be great help if I could implement these frameworks.

Comment: You can't use bundling directly in ASP classic, but you could use the workaround described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23500058/asp-net-mvc-bundles-in-classic-asp-or-php-etc

Comment: Awesome. That will help me.

Comment: Or you can use bundling and minification in your appstart.cshtml page and then those bundles will be available to classic asp / php or whatever pages run in your application including plain old html.